# Android - How to calculate one edit text and divide another value?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am a total beginner, I am wondering if anyone could help me out with the code. I am trying to make ideal daily water intake apps.

There will be only one edit text for user to input their weight and I want it to divide for example 0.024. Have button to calculate and then display the answer on screen.

```
public class WaterCalculate extends Activity {

    //Declare textviews as fields, so they can be accessed throughout the activity.
    EditText weightuser;
    TextView tv4; 
    ImageButton calculate;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.water_calculate);

        //Bind the EditText views

        weightuser = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.weight);
        tv4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.res);

        calculate =  (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.calc);
        calculate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
               calculate();
        }
        });
    }

        private void calculate() {
             //get entered texts from the edittexts,and convert to integers.
            Double value1 = Double.parseDouble(weightuser.getText().toString());
            //do the calculation
            Double calculatedValue = (value1/0.024);
            //set the value to the textview, to display on screen.
            tv4.setText(String.valueOf("You need " + calculatedValue + "\nliters of water per day" ));
        }

}
```

When i run the apps the button to calculate its not working and it show the app has stopped. Appreciate for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought the problem is in this line.

```
 tv4.setText(String.valueOf("You need " + calculatedValue + "\nliters of water per day" ));
```

Give a try like this...

```
tv4.setText("You need "+Double.toString(calculatedValue)+"\nliters of water per day");
```

and also ensure that you catched the exceptions at necessary places like converting editText value into double.

Comment: I already change it to string but still not working. Maybe the code was fine but i dont know where the error is. Btw thank you    @Vishwa

Comment: @Ell at first ensure used view ids are available in your parent layout.Then try the whole code inside the try and catch.You will get the type of an exception.based on the exceptions will help you to find out the solution.

Answer (score -1):

Try the below code, am sure it will work, when you use click listener for button you should use `View.Onclick`

```
class WaterCalculate extends Activity {

    // Declare textviews as fields, so they can be accessed throughout the
    // activity.
    EditText weightuser;
    TextView tv4;
    ImageButton calculate;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.water_calculate);

        // Bind the EditText views

        weightuser = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weight);
        tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.res);

        calculate = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.calc);

        calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                calculate();
            }
        });
    }

    private void calculate() {
        // get entered texts from the edittexts,and convert to integers.
        Double value1 = Double.parseDouble(weightuser.getText().toString());
        // do the calculation
        Double calculatedValue = (value1 / 0.024);
        // set the value to the textview, to display on screen.
        tv4.setText(String.valueOf("You need " + calculatedValue
                + "\nliters of water per day"));
    }

}
```

Comment: I have try but still when i click the button the apps has stopped. Thanks for  the answer @Madhu

Comment: Sorry but i didn't clicking on it. But your answer is useful. Thank you again.  @Madhu